# Validation trouble on new records

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

I have few assessment records that have to be created. I have written a validation where they can create new record with the minimum due date of 7 days from the created date.

AND( 
OR( 
ISPICKVAL( Assessment_Request_Type__c , "priority") 
), 
LEN(WorkType.Name) > 12 , 
Assessment_Due_Date__c <= ( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate) + 7) 
)

The problem is, this validation is also firing when i am trying to update the existing assessment records.

How can I make sense to have the validation rule check and say that it's ok if the existing record (Using ISNEW() ) & the Assessment Due Date isn't changing. (Using ISCHANGED).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly, you can combine the requirements inside your `AND()` function:

```
AND(
    OR(
        ISNEW(),
        ISCHANGED(Assessment_Due_Date__c),
    ),
    ISPICKVAL(Assessment_Request_Type__c , "priority"), 
    LEN(WorkType.Name) > 12 ,
    Assessment_Due_Date__c <= (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7)
)
```

This validation rule will return true if the record is new or if the assessment due date is changing, and the other conditions you had initially are true.

If the Assessment Due Date is not supposed to change at all you could also consider creating separate validation rules for simplicity.